# Configuring Cassandra as primary data store in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, cassandra-jdbc, wso2-identity-server

We have install WSO2 Identity Server 4.6.0 and would like to use Cassandra s the primary data store as well as user store manager.

We have not found a clear path to get this implemented.

Can anyone give us a clear path on how to configure this data source and use it as the primary and only data source?

Thank you,

Comment: - We have install Apache Cassandra on a remote server
- Installed Cassandra-JDBC-1.1.1 Server under Feature Mangement
- Modified the master-datasource.xml by adding a new datastore section configuring URL pointing to the remote server.

Next we need to know how to configure this new user store in user-mgt.xml in order to use it in "User Store Management"

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra user store can be plugged with WSO2 Identity Server as custom user store.  You need to implement it according to your requirement... You can use `AbstractUserStoreManager` and implement the required methods of it...  There is an example custom user store implementations that you can find from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2014/02/25/how-to-wso2is-writing-custom-user-store-manager/). It has been written for a custom JDBC based user store.. And only users and user attributes are read from the user store...  Actually, If you want such limited functions with your Cassandra user store,  you can directly extended from `JDBCUserStoreManager`  Also i have found some source regarding Cassandra user store for Identity Server from [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/cassandra-userstore/org.wso2.carbon.user.cassandra/) But it is little bit older source.. But It would help to get some idea ..